# Late posting is Possible in facebook from android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing one android app in that i have to post some message into Facebook.and that message will post only when my WiFi/Network connection is on, otherwise that text run on background till my WiFi is on.when WiFi is on that message will post.Is it possible?. Sorry if my question is write in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need **[offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)**.

> Enables your app to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user
>   at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time
>   period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user
>   when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the
>   access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.